# how to move the template?

Tags: python, django

please tell me how to move the view (view.py) in the directory "views".

Now the structure of my folders and files is as follows:

```
proj1(catalog)
    views.py(file)
    manage.py(file)
    proj1(catalog)
        wsgi.py(file)
        urls.py(file)
        settings.py(file)
        __init__.py(file)
        views(catalog)
```

urls.py following content:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',   
    url('^$', views.hello),
    url('^datetime$', views.current_datetime),
    url('^dt$', views.current_datetime),
    url('^dt/(\d{0,2})$', views.current_datetime2),
)
```

I need to file located in the directory view.py proj1/proj1 /. 
wherein static pages is still made ​​available to the browser.

the problem is that I do not know how to change the code in the files: urls.py, settings.py

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change views, just do in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/path/to/proj1/proj1/views/', # or another path with templates
   'django/contrib/admin/templates/'
)
```

Comment: in my settings.py does not exist TEMPLATE_DIRS.
http://prozaik.16mb.com/misc/settings.txt